# Can not sum GridView column with a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to sum GridView column value with a variable and show the result in second column.  I am trying to do this.But when I convert the GirdView column into an integer the following

"Input string was not in a correct format."  Error is occuring.

```
long openingBalace = 5000;      
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    long sum = openingBalace + Convert.ToInt64((GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Text));
    GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before convert you can check value is a numeric using Regex `Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\d+$")`.

```
  long openingBalace = 5000;
  for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
      string input = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Text;
      if (Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\d+$"))
      {
           long sum = openingBalace + Convert.ToInt64(input);
           GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Text = sum.ToString();
      }
   }
```

Also you can use `TryParse()` and check result and add `num`

```
long num = 0;
bool result = long.TryParse(input, out num);
```

Comment: is there any way?? it is not working for me @M. Wiśnicki

Comment: This error clearly tell that parsing value is not correct. What you mean "it is not working for me"? Which part of code not working? Its simple you get values from your grid, check it before parse and its all.